# SyncFusion front-end errors in Blazor WebAssembly app

Tags: razor, server, blazor, webassembly, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion in Blazor WebAssembly and encountering issues upon building the application on my local server. The first issue is that the Syncfusion components are not displaying properly: the calendar widget (*see image*) is not formatted properly. The second issue is that the widget has no functionality: i.e., the buttons are broken. This same issue occurs with all Syncfusion components.

This is how the calendar component renders in the application:

[image: Calendar]

I have attached a few relevant code snippets from the project.

**Program.cs [snippet]**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Syncfusion.Blazor;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
app.Run();
```

**Index.razor [snippet]:**

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Calendars

<SfCalendar TValue="DateTime" />
```

**Host.cshtml [snippet]**

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--Use below script reference if you are using Syncfusion.Blazor Single NuGet-->
    <script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Core/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

I hypothesize that I must be missing some CSS and script import, based on the nature of the problem. I have tried adding references as recommended in Syncfusion's [documentation](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/getting-started/blazor-webassembly-visual-studio) to Host.cshtml (the project does not use index.html) but the references in `<head>` did not affect the application components.

Comment: Check in Browser Tools (F12 in the Browser) that the files are being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided details, I assume you used Syncfusion Individual NuGet in Blazor WebAssembly Application with Prerendering.

To resolve the issue you have to ensure that you have referred [Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/) NuGet. And then refer [this](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/common/how-to/create-blazor-webassembly-prerendering#create-a-new-project-for-blazor-webassembly-aspnet-core-hosted-applicationfor) for details regarding creating Blazor WebAssembly Application with Prerendering.

By the way, you only need to refer script of Individual NuGet, but you have referred script of Single NuGet package also, which is unnecessary.

Image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I updated my `Host.cshtml` file according to the Syncfusion doc. I also installed the `Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes` NuGet. The result is that the Syncfusion components display but they still do not have functionality. The `js` script, then, seems to not be working properly in the body component of the `Host.cshtml` file.

Comment: You are supposed to set the value of the render-mode attribute to 'WebAssemblyPrerendered' for a Blazor WebAssembly application with prerendering. You can do this by adding the following code snippet:
 

__Host.schtml:_

`<componenttype="typeof(App)"render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered"/>`

 

As mentioned earlier, refer to [this](https://blazor.syncfusion.com/documentation/common/how-to/create-blazor-webassembly-prerendering#resolving-httpclient-errors-on-webassembly-prerendering) for more details.